# Testing images with OpenCV and Doctest

Tags: python, opencv, doctest

so what I am trying to do is use doctest to test the result of a series of functions in Python which use OpenCV to return a series of images. As I'm sure you know, images are nothing but a matrix.

How can I use Doctest to check if the returned image is the same as a previously saved one? Not entirely sure if this is the right method to test this, so if you have a better idea please don't be shy (it's mandatory that my functions return an image).

Desirable solution is not copying the whole matrix as the test result (I'd rather change my test method as it would make the files unreadable).

Comment: Why not just open the saved image and check if it's equal to the return value? `doctest` might not be the best testing tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was quite simple, just didn't understand well the use of doctest.

To do what I was asking:

````
def myfuntion():
    ```
    >>> isinstance(myfunction(), np.ndarray)
    True
    ```
````

Although this test doesn't check that the output image is a correct results, it tests that is an np.array, which was what I needed.